# Galaxy rotation curve and dark matter

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, astrophysics

I am reading "The Essential Cosmic Perspective" by Jeffrey O. Bennett, Megan O. Donahue, Nicholas Schneider, Mark Voit.
In Chapter 14, it is stated that an evidence of the presence of dark matter in our galaxy is that the rotational curve does not match that obtained from calculation.
In the calculation, the following formula is used
$$M_r=\frac{rv^2}{G}$$
where $M_r$ is the mass enclosed inside a radius $r$ from the galactic center.

My understanding is that the above equation is a result of the shell theorem. But we know that shell theorem applies to spherically symmetric mass distribution only, and most galaxies are disks. So why can we still do this?

Comment: [Galaxies have bulges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulge_(astronomy))

Comment: source provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two points here. First, the mass is more spherically distributed than one would expect from images. There is something like 5 times as much dark matter as baryonic matter, so even if all the baryonic matter is in a disk, the dark matter [halo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter_halo) will be spherical and this will dominate the potential.

Second, in practice we don't in fact make the assumption of sphericity to conclude there is missing mass. You can look at the stars in a galaxy and model its disk-shaped potential and then ask what velocities things should have. You get the wrong answer as a function of radius in the plane of the disk. Moreover, you find that orbital velocities *are* more or less spherically symmetric in the region around a galaxy, giving further evidence that the matter we see cannot be the whole story. For example, this was done for objects orbiting our galaxy in [this paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005MNRAS.364..433B).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. FYI, question edited with source provided.

Comment: I think OP's confusion here lies in the fact that for the shell theorem to apply, the mass distribution must have spherical symmetry, but there must not be mass everywhere on the sphere, right?