# Galaxy rotation curve

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

In calculating galaxies' rotation curve, it is assumed that masses outside the orbit has no contribution and masses inside the orbit can be deemed as if they were at the center, just like the case of shell theorem. But we know that shell theorem applies to spherically symmetric mass distribution only, and most galaxies are disks. So why can we still do this?

Comment: http://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_formal_proof_or_justification_for_applying_two-body_gravitational_equations_such_as_v_SqrtG_M_r_to_spiral_galaxy_disks

Comment: Er ... do serious calculation actually assume that, or just the toy ones used to hurry explanation along?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Galaxy rotation curve and dark matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113497/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the rules are on repeating questions on multipLe stack exchange sites? Anyway, I'll just repeat the answer I've given to the same OP on Astronomy SE.

We can't. That is an over simplification only used in elementary treatments. If you see it done somewhere in the refereed literature, it is probably incorrect. Of course it may be true that the mass is almost spherically symmetric, especially if it is dominated by a spherically symmetric dark matter component, but that the visible light is not. A galaxy rotation curve makes no such assumption, it is merely a measurement of rotation speed as a function of radius. It is only the interpretation that needs to deal with the mass distribution.

The real situation is much more complex. See for example http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Battaner/revision.html

However, even if one assumed all the mass was concentrated into a disk-like shape, the only way you can get flat rotation curves is to assume that the mass in the disk does not "follow the light" - that the mass-to-luminosity ratio increases vastly with radius - which is essentially still saying that you have "dark matter", just in a disk.

However, we know from looking at the dynamics of stars with respect to the disk (i.e. their vertical velocity dispersion as a function of distance from the plane) that the local disk mass density is almost identical to the sum of the densities that can be attributed to stars, gas and stellar remnants. Therefore there is no huge amount of dark matter *in the disk*, baryonic or otherwise. So a disk-only solution does not work and we are forced to consider a spherical distribution of dark matter, which explains the rotation curve and, if it is non-baryonic, would not be *expected* to collapse into a disk-like geometry.